# How to pass Byref argument in python function

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I am new to Python and in the beginer level. I want to pass an argument as Byref similar to what we use in vb or c#.

Below is my code. But i am not getting the expected Output.

Thank you for the help in advance

```
class calculator:
    arg = 0
    globvar = 0   
 
    def add(a,b):
        global globvar
        globvar = a + b
        print("Inside function call",globvar)
             

    print("Before function call",globvar)
    add(2,4)
    print("After function call",globvar)
```

```
Output

Before function call 0
Inside function call 6
After function call 0
```

The after function should update to 6. But it is still displaying 0

Comment: The concept doesn't exist in Python.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pass-by-reference (or any other style of argument passing). The issue is that the global variable `globvar` is different from the name `globvar` that exists inside the namespace of the `class` statement when you call `add`. While you *can* execute arbitrary code in  `class` statement, you usually restrict yourself to assignments (to define class attributes) and `def` statements (to define methods).

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected if you get rid of the unnecessary `class` statement.

```
globvar = 0   

def add(a,b):
    global globvar
    globvar = a + b
    print("Inside function call",globvar)
         

print("Before function call",globvar)
add(2,4)
print("After function call",globvar)
```